# Print to file without clear character

Tags: linux, command-line, files, terminal

I want to print the output of docker stats to file.

For example, I am running:

```
docker stats --format "{{ .Name }},{{ .MemUsage }},{{ .MemPerc }},{{ .CPUPerc }}" > /home/test.txt
```

However, since the normal output of docker stats is on one line which is updated, in the file I have the clear character (^[[3J^[[H^[[2J) printed out.

How can I print the output without having that character?

I also attach a picture to make clear what I have in output.

[image]

Comment: BTW, didn't you mean `/home/<USER>/test.txt` or more easily `~/test.txt`?

Comment: yes...I removed my user name only for the example

Comment: There is no need, Bash and other shells can expand `~`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pipe it through [ansifilter](http://www.andre-simon.de/doku/ansifilter/en/sfnet.php):

```
docker stats --format "{{ .Name }},{{ .MemUsage }},{{ .MemPerc }},{{ .CPUPerc }}"  | ansifilter > /home/test.txt
```

Notice that `/home/test.txt` will contain multiple lines. It will look something like this:

```
alpine,656KiB / 7.476GiB,0.01%,0.00%
alpine,656KiB / 7.476GiB,0.01%,0.00%
alpine,656KiB / 7.476GiB,0.01%,0.00%
alpine,656KiB / 7.476GiB,0.01%,0.00%
alpine,656KiB / 7.476GiB,0.01%,0.00%
alpine,656KiB / 7.476GiB,0.01%,0.00%
alpine,656KiB / 7.476GiB,0.01%,0.00%
alpine,656KiB / 7.476GiB,0.01%,0.00%
alpine,656KiB / 7.476GiB,0.01%,0.00%
alpine,656KiB / 7.476GiB,0.01%,0.00%
alpine,528KiB / 7.476GiB,0.01%,0.00%
alpine,528KiB / 7.476GiB,0.01%,0.00%
alpine,528KiB / 7.476GiB,0.01%,0.03%
alpine,528KiB / 7.476GiB,0.01%,0.03%
alpine,528KiB / 7.476GiB,0.01%,0.02%
```

Comment: thank you very much! it works!

Comment: We should both thank [André Simon](http://www.andre-simon.de) for creating this tool.